# I'm having the error after installing flutter and running flutter doctor in my CMD

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm get this error message

C:\Users\labeg>flutter doctor
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
Resolving dependencies in ....\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools... (2:54.8s)
Got socket error trying to find package test at https://pub.dev.
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory
....\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools get --example"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
}
exit code: 69

I tried Flutter doctor in my CMD after following all the installation processes on the flutter official site.

Comment: Could you share your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.